# How to switch between multiple files in UNIX while using VI editor?

Tags: unix, vi

I'm new to UNIX. I am using VI editor to code for C programming. 
If I open multiple files at a time using VI editor like,

```
vi *.c
```

I can edit the first file only. If I press ":wq", it shows me that there are: "6 more files to edit"

How can I switch between those files?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Next file: `:n`

Previous file: `:p`, `:N` or `:prev` depending on which vi implementation you're using.

Here's a typical cheat sheet which has a section "Files" on this topic.

http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi2.html

Answer (score 5):

For Linux Red-Hat VI version 7.2.411 use :n and :N to switch next and previous.

Comment: Also works on Mac OS X (which is BSD). Not sure about "real" BSD vi.

Answer (score 2):

AIX's vi has it's own commands; it took me a while to find this information because the answers in this question didn't have it already, so I'll add this answer.

Neither `:p`, `:N`, nor `:prev` work to go to the previous file, you need to use one of the variations of the `:n ---` command.

The `:n` for moving to the next file is the same

Use `:n file_name` to move to a certain file (Can open new files this way too) (To go to the previous file, just do this with the previous file's name

Use `:n list of file names` to define a new list of files to edit (In this case, the files `list`, `of`, `file`, and `names` would be opened in series using `:n` after running `:n list of file names`

Other useful results from the man pages

```
   :e File
        Edits the specified file. If you are using this subcommand 
        from the ex editor, you do not need to type the : (colon).
   :e!
        Re-edits the current file and discards all changes.
   :e + File
        Edits the specified file starting at the end.
   :e + Number File
        Edits the specified file starting at the specified line number.
   :e #
        Edits the alternate file. The alternate file is usually the 
        previous file name before accessing another file with a 
        :e command. However, if changes are pending on the current 
        file when a new file is called, the new file becomes the 
        alternate file. This subcommand is the same as the Ctrl-A 
        subcommand.
   Ctrl-G
        Shows the current file name, current line number, number of 
        lines in the file, and percentage of the way through the 
        file where the cursor is located.
```

Answer (score 2):

#### plus two more, :first & :last

ig:

~# vi foo*.c

---

:n

```
Next File
```

:N

```
Last File
```

:b1

:first

```
First File
```

:last

```
Last File
```

:b`#`

```
`#` switch to buffer `N` file
```

Answer (score 1):

:b# is working in vi editor to open particular file, when multiple files are opened, # means numbers here

Answer (score -1):

`:e#` where # is the file number

Comment: er that creates a file named '#' (whatever number you put there)